# How to multiply all data in column?

Tags: r

I am new for R program and I have a problem that I don't know if I would like to multiply all data in one column together. I don't which command will work.

Thank you for your help and support.

Best Regards,

Jumpot Sa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `prod`

```
prod(df1$col1)
#[1] 479001600
```

Another option is `Reduce` with `*`

```
Reduce(`*`, df1$col1)
#[1] 479001600
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:12, col2 = rnorm(12))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I tried to use prod() but it's show NA. is it because my data is xts colume or not ?

Comment: @JumpotSangchantrarin  You haven't provided a reproducible example.  I showed one example where it doesn't show any NA.

Comment: Dear akrun, Thank you for your support. I found out why it can't use prod() because it was contain a NA in data. After I remove it's out. It's work.